# Configuring Kerberos with Host-Named Site Collections

Tags: kerberos, host-named, hnsc

So I created a Single Web Application: rootsite.contoso.com with a Root Site Collection.  I set the Authentication in the Web App to use Kerberos and then Set the SPN for the AppPool account running the Web App with `HTTP/rootsite.contoso.com` and `HTTP/rootsite`.

Checking for Kerberos via Fiddler and it works, wonderful.  However, now it seams I have to Add Each Host-Named Site Collection to the same Service Account running the AppPool in order for these sites to render via Kerberos.

Is this correct?  I'm concerned first that it's a maintenance issue, and second, that the list of SPN values will get out of hand.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need an SPN for every hostname site collection URL. Technically, we need a SPN for all the url which leads us to get the web application.

Number of SPN depends upon number HNSC collections, tough job.

Comment: So, I could conceivably overrun the hard coded 8k limit ?

Comment: 8K limit, which limit we are talking about?

Comment: I may be wrong in this particular area, I don't think its Token Bloat but I believe there is a limit to the multi-string value.  How is MS doing this in the Cloud?